# Updating the table giving undefined offset in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am reading a file and once reading below is the csv_array data:

```
Array (
    [0] => "1"
    [1] => "1468409102803"
    [2] => "dd 22"
    [3] => "test1"
    [4] => "test2"
    [5] => "test3"
    [6] => "testcity"
    [7] => "11111"
    [8] => ""
    [9] => ""
    [10] => "1234567"
    [11] => "GI230"
    [12] => "Eveready Reachargeable Torch DL91"
    [13] => "1"
)
```

Taking above array updating the orders table as below:

```
DB::table('orders')->where('order_number',$csv_array[1])->update(array('ship_address1'=>$csv_array['3'],'ship_address2'=>$csv_array['4'],'ship_address3'=>$csv_array['5'],'ship_city'=>$csv_array['6'],'ship_zip'=>$csv_array['7']));
```

Error coming is:

> undefined offset 1

Comment: check `print_r($csv_array)` its a array or string in array format.

Comment: please remove quotes from array like $csv_array[3] and check

Comment: try `dd($csv_array[1]);` and see what are you getting

Comment: @Aleksandar Vasić :   its giving string(15) ""1468409102803"" if i try dd($csv_array[1]);

Comment: the issue is not from the arrays, they are ok..i tested it...try to contruct the array before using update() and give it the constructed array update($contructedArray)...

Comment: can anyone help me out !!!!!

Comment: look into your laravel.log and show us backtrace for this exception

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

I thought you are made the mistake of **array key**

```
DB::table('orders')->where('order_number',$csv_array[1])->update(array('ship_address1'=>$csv_array['3'],'ship_address2'=>$csv_array['4'],'ship_address3'=>$csv_array['5'],'ship_city'=>$csv_array['6'],'ship_zip'=>$csv_array['7']));
```

Into

```
DB::table('orders')->whereIn('order_number',$csv_array[1])->update(array('ship_address1'=>$csv_array[3],'ship_address2'=>$csv_array[4],'ship_address3'=>$csv_array[5],'ship_city'=>$csv_array[6],'ship_zip'=>$csv_array[7]));
```

Comment: @sivashanker Now i changed where to whereIn please check this and let me know

Comment: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array  this is the error i am getting